# ConEmu を開かずに外部から設定を変更したい

Tags: conemu

フリーのConEmuというコンソールを使っているのですが、設定をミスったせいで起動時にエラーがでて開かなくなりました。こういう場合当該ソフトを開かずに外部から設定を変更する方法はあるのでしょうか。ConEmuに限った話でなくても結構です。

一度ConEmuをアンインストールしてProgram Files以下にあるフォルダも消して、新しくインストールし直したのですが、まだ設定が残っているようでエラーがでて開けませんでした。このような場合どこに設定ファイルは残っているのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @oTak
ご回答ありがとうございます。解決しました。
レジストリはほとんどいじったことがなかったので、エクスプローラーで「ConEmu」と検索すると、「ConEmu.xml」という設定ファイルが出てきたのでこれを削除してインストールし直しました。

Comment: 自力で解決したのであれば、その内容を自分で「回答」として投稿し、それの横に出てくるであろうチェックマークを押して「承認」してください。承認された回答が無い質問はいつまでも未回答として残ってしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

https://osdn.jp/projects/conemu/wiki/FrontPage

上記サイトに、

> すべての設定はレジストリ(複数の設定がサポートされています)から読み込まれた後に、コマンドラインパラメータが適用されます。 /Config と /BufferHeight パラメータはコマンドラインにおいてのみ。 ほとんどの設定はコマンドラインからではなく設定ダイアログから変更します。

と記載されています。
実際にインストールして確認したわけではありませんが、まずはレジストリを確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。